# Dynamically format string using python format

Tags: python

I have to variables `one="{}{}{}T{}:{}:{}" and two='2021,-10,-28,05,40,33'` When i try to use print(one.format(two)) i am getting errors. `IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple.` guessing it is because the two variable is being seen as a string.
So I switched and tried to do the `*args` method.

```
for item in two:
  item = str(item)
  data[item] = ''
result = template.format(*data)
```

However if I switch `two='2021,-10,-28,00,00,00.478'` it fails because a dictionary is unique.  so how do i get the first method to work or is there a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split the `two` into list and then unpack it with `*`

```
one="{}{}{}T{}:{}:{}"
two='2021,-10,-28,05,40,33'

print(one.format(*two.split(','))) # 2021-10-28T05:40:33
```

Comment: You are a genius.  Didn't ever cross my mind.